# Trying to serve static content from my SpringBoot app, but it fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to serve static files from my SpringBoot application. I have this very simple controller that I wish does the stuff:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@RestController
public class MyRestController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
               .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static")
               .addResourceLocations("file:/static");
   }

   @PostMapping(path = "/hello")
   public MyResponse hello(@RequestBody() MyBody body,
                         HttpServletRequest request) {
       return new MyResponse("Hello " + request.getRemoteAddr());
   }
}
```

My index.html file resides in the *static* folder:

```
MyApp/
   src/
      main/
         static/index.html
         static/img/image.png
```

When I do a GET request with curl to http://localhost:8080 the I get response code 404 in return and the server states `No mapping for GET /`.
I expect that the index.html file is returned.

Sending a POST request to `http://localhost:8080/hello` with a `MyBody` object as a json body works though!

What have I done wrong?

I have read this [blogpost](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) from the Spring site, but it seems quiet old since that post was published in 2013. Maybe it works different today?

Comment: You should NOT use EnableWebMvc in Spring Boot. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue! If you post that as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use EnableWebMvc in Spring Boot. See [the](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration) [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

This is mentioned in the Spring Boot [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/), under the spring mvc section you can use WebMvcConfigurer, but you do not need to do @EnableWebMvc

So you should remove the @EnableWebMvc annotation!

```
//@EnableWebMvc Remove this
@RestController
public class MyRestController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
               .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static")
               .addResourceLocations("file:/static");
   }

   @PostMapping(path = "/hello")
   public MyResponse hello(@RequestBody() MyBody body,
                         HttpServletRequest request) {
       return new MyResponse("Hello " + request.getRemoteAddr());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static resources usually go under /src/main/resources to get onto the classpath in the maven standard project layout, and Spring Boot should serve all files under /static (/src/main/resources/static) without any `addResourceHandler()` application configuration.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing your **resources** folder, your folder structure should look like

```
MyApp/
    src/
      main/
        resources/
          static/index.html
          static/img/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog application that receives uploaded images in a folder that can be outside static/.

```
MyApp/
src/
  main/
    resources/
          static/
              css/
              javascript/
              images/
          blog/
              1-blogpost/ (here are the uploaded images)
              2-blogpost/ (here are the uploaded images)
              (... and so on)
```

So i made this in Kotlin with Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
class WebConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {

    private val logger = loggerFactory.getLogger(WebConfiguration::class.java)

    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        logger.info("####### Entering ResourceHandlers configurations #######")
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        registry.addResourceHandler("/blog/**").addResourceLocations("file:src/main/resources/blog/")
    }

    @Bean
    fun restTemplate() : RestTemplate {
        return RestTemplate()
    }
}
```